# datatable into cakephp join tables

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, datatable, left-join

I have problem with datatables and script from
http://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_cake to cakephp. 
I using it many time but no I have to use join and server response me

> MySQL Error: 1052.

Problem is in this line :

```
$sTable = "`clients` AS c JOIN users AS u ON (c.user_id = u.id)";
```

When I print my all query and paste it in phpmyadmin everything is OK, but cake get error.

My generated SELECT :

> SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS c.id, c.name, c.nip, c.adress, c.tel,
>   c.tel2, c.email, c.created, c.id
>               FROM   clients c join users u ON(c.user_id = u.id)
>
> ```
>         ORDER BY   c.id asc
>         LIMIT 0, 10
> ```

@edit

I modificated my script and now it generate something like this:

> SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
>   `c`.`id`,`c`.`name`,`c`.`nip`,`c`.`adress`,`c`.`tel`,`c`.`tel2`,`c`.`email`,`c`.`created`,`c`.`id`
>               FROM   `clients` AS `c` join `users` AS  `u` ON `c`.`user_id` = `u`.`id`
>
> ```
>         ORDER BY   `c`.`name` asc
>         LIMIT 0, 10
> ```

But it's still not work. (I used char '`' before prefix and after and col name. )

Comment: Post the full error and SQL.

Comment: The problem is in the query it self. There is a ambiguous field in the query. Can you post the full query?

Comment: I changed my first post. I added all generated query. I can't get all mysql error because I see only MySQL Error: 1052.

Answer (score 0):

you need create a view with the relationship!!

1. Create the VIEW in MySql:

   ```
   CREATE VIEW 'the_view' AS
       SELECT 
           a.id, 
           a.num_factura_proveedor, 
           b.nombre_comercial 
       FROM compras a  
           INNER JOIN terceros b ON a.tercero_id = b.id
   ```
2. on the server side script:

   ```
   $sTable = "the_view";

   //the columns of the view

   $aColumns = array('id' , 'num_factura_proveedor', 'nombre_comercial');

   $sIndexColumn = "id";
   ```